# Add new Action to the existing Shopping Cart Price Rules Actions

Tags: php, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Admin Panel -> Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules -> Add New Rule -> Actions (Tab)

In the **Update prices using the following information** For the **Apply** Dropdown i Want to add my custom Option.

[image]

How do i do that.

How do i Do that with out effecting the Core Functionalities...

I did some research for this i never find any article for Overriding the Promotions.

Started overriding the Core files for that i found i should override the following things.

1. **/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Actions.php**
2. **/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule.php**
3. **/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php**

In my **local** Codepool created file like `Mage1/Adminhtml` `Mage1/SalesRule`

My new module folder structure

1. **/app/code/local/Mage1/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Actions.php**
2. **/app/code/local/Mage1/SalesRule/Model/Rule.php**
3. **/app/code/local/Mage1/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php**

**Mage1/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage1_Adminhtml>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mage1_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <rule>Mage1_SalesRule_Model_Rule</rule>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <promo_quote_edit_tab_actions>Mage1_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions</promo_quote_edit_tab_actions>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <adminhtml>
                <class>Mage1_Adminhtml_Helper</class>
            </adminhtml>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Mage1/SalesRule/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage1_SalesRule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mage1_SalesRule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>     
                    <validator>Mage1_SalesRule_Model_Validator</validator>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <salesrule>
                <class>Mage1_SalesRule_Helper</class>
            </salesrule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Actions.php**

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
        $model = Mage::registry('current_promo_quote_rule');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('action_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Update prices using the following information')));
        $fieldset->addField('simple_action', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply'),
            'name'      => 'simple_action',
            'options'    => array(
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Percent of product price discount'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Fixed amount discount'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Fixed amount discount for whole cart'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::GET_PERCENT_X_MAX_Y_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Percent of total cart Max discount'),
            ),
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('discount_amount', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_amount',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-not-negative-number',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Discount Amount'),
        ));
        $model->setDiscountAmount($model->getDiscountAmount()*1);
        $fieldset->addField('discount_qty', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_qty',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To'),
        ));
        $model->setDiscountQty($model->getDiscountQty()*1);
        $fieldset->addField('discount_step', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_step',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Discount Qty Step (Buy X)'),
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('apply_to_shipping', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply to Shipping Amount'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply to Shipping Amount'),
            'name'      => 'apply_to_shipping',
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('simple_free_shipping', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Free Shipping'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Free Shipping'),
            'name'      => 'simple_free_shipping',
            'options'    => array(
                0 => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('No'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::FREE_SHIPPING_ITEM => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('For matching items only'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::FREE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('For shipment with matching items'),
            ),
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('stop_rules_processing', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Stop Further Rules Processing'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Stop Further Rules Processing'),
            'name'      => 'stop_rules_processing',
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('No'),
            ),
        ));
        $renderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset')
            ->setTemplate('promo/fieldset.phtml')
            ->setNewChildUrl($this->getUrl('*/promo_quote/newActionHtml/form/rule_actions_fieldset'));
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('actions_fieldset', array(
            'legend'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)')
        ))->setRenderer($renderer);
        $fieldset->addField('actions', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'actions',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply To'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply To'),
            'required' => true,
        ))->setRule($model)->setRenderer(Mage::getBlockSingleton('rule/actions'));
        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform', array('form' => $form));
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        if ($model->isReadonly()) {
            foreach ($fieldset->getElements() as $element) {
                $element->setReadonly(true, true);
            }
        }
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

**Rule.php**

```
const TO_PERCENT_ACTION = 'to_percent';
const BY_PERCENT_ACTION = 'by_percent';
const TO_FIXED_ACTION   = 'to_fixed';
const BY_FIXED_ACTION   = 'by_fixed';
const CART_FIXED_ACTION = 'cart_fixed';
const BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION = 'buy_x_get_y';
const GET_PERCENT_X_MAX_Y_ACTION = 'get_x_max_y';
```

**Validator.php**

```
public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item) {
    Mage::log('I'm Inside Process Function');
    switch ($rule->getSimpleAction()) {
        case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::GET_PERCENT_X_MAX_Y_ACTION:
            Mage::log('Helllll..');
            break;
    }
}
```

Because of Actions.php & Rule.php files editing i should get a new option in Dropdown But i'm not getting anything. Anything wrong i did here.

I Hope Some thing i'm missing in XML files.

Any ideas ?

Help me please...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Shopping Cart Price Rules in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484856/override-shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using event ***adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform***. See the example below:

**Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml:**

```
 <adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform>
            <observers>
                <add_custom_salesrule_actions>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>addCustomSalesRuleAction</method>
                </add_custom_salesrule_actions>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

And them:

**Namespace_Module_Model_Observer.php**

```
public function addCustomSalesRuleAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $form = $observer->getEvent()->getForm();
    $element = $form->getElement('simple_action');
    $values = $element->getValues();
    $values[Namespace_Module_Model_Rule::CUSTOM_ACTION] = 'Your custom action Label';
    $element->setValues($values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.0.0

my folders and files

1. **/app/code/local/Mage1/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Actions.php**
2. **/app/code/local/Mage1/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml****

Actions.php

```
class Mage1_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('current_promo_quote_rule');

        //$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form1', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post'));
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('action_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Update prices using the following information')));

        $fieldset->addField('simple_action', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply'),
            'name'      => 'simple_action',
            'options'    => array(
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Percent of product price discount'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Fixed amount discount'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Fixed amount discount for whole cart'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::Your_Action => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Your_Action)'), // Add your action
            ),
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('discount_amount', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_amount',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-not-negative-number',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Discount Amount'),
        ));
        $model->setDiscountAmount($model->getDiscountAmount()*1);

        $fieldset->addField('discount_qty', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_qty',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To'),
        ));
        $model->setDiscountQty($model->getDiscountQty()*1);

        $fieldset->addField('discount_step', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'discount_step',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Discount Qty Step (Buy X)'),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('apply_to_shipping', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply to Shipping Amount'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply to Shipping Amount'),
            'name'      => 'apply_to_shipping',
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('simple_free_shipping', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Free Shipping'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Free Shipping'),
            'name'      => 'simple_free_shipping',
            'options'    => array(
                0 => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('No'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::FREE_SHIPPING_ITEM => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('For matching items only'),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::FREE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('For shipment with matching items'),
            ),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('stop_rules_processing', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Stop Further Rules Processing'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Stop Further Rules Processing'),
            'name'      => 'stop_rules_processing',
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('No'),
            ),
        ));

        $renderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset')
            ->setTemplate('promo/fieldset.phtml')
            ->setNewChildUrl($this->getUrl('*/promo_quote/newActionHtml/form/rule_actions_fieldset'));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('actions_fieldset', array(
            'legend'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)')
        ))->setRenderer($renderer);

        $fieldset->addField('actions', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'actions',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply To'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply To'),
            'required' => true,
        ))->setRule($model)->setRenderer(Mage::getBlockSingleton('rule/actions'));

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform', array('form' => $form));

        $form->setValues($model->getData());

        if ($model->isReadonly()) {
            foreach ($fieldset->getElements() as $element) {
                $element->setReadonly(true, true);
            }
        }
        //$form->setUseContainer(true);

        $this->setForm($form);

        return $this; // replace parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage1_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mage1_Adminhtml>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <promo_quote_edit_tab_actions>Mage1_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions</promo_quote_edit_tab_actions>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

don't forget enable you module in app/etc/modules

work for me

best regards!

Comment: Hi. You solution worked but I am curious why should you return $this instead of parent::_prepareForm ?

Answer (score 1):

**Using** `parent::_prepareForm()`

```
return parent::_prepareForm();
```

What it Should Be:

```
return $this;
```

Comment: Why should return $this instead of parent::_prepareForm()?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to add/remove shopping cart price rule Actions.

```
<?php

class Custom_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Actions
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();
        $form = $this->getForm()->getElements();
        $fieldset = $form[0];
        $elements = $fieldset->getSortedElements();
        foreach($elements as $element) {
            if ($element->getId() == "simple_action") {
                $options = $element->getOptions();
                $new_options = array(
                    Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Text 1'),
                    Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::TO_PERCENT_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Text 2'),
                    Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Text 3'),
                    Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::TO_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Text 4'),
                    Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Text 5'),
                    Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Text 6'),
                );
                $element->setValues($new_options);
                break;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you just want to add an option in dropdown go to `Core > Mage > Adminhtml > Block > Promo > Quote > Edit > Tab > Actions.php` and add an option to the array

```
$fieldset->addField('simple_action', 'select', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply'),
        'name'      => 'simple_action',
        'options'    => array(
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_PERCENT_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Percent of product price discount'),
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BY_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Fixed amount discount'),
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::CART_FIXED_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Fixed amount discount for whole cart'),
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::BUY_X_GET_Y_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)'),
            Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::Your_Custom_ACTION => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Custom Action Text'),

        ),
    ));
```

And also go to

`Mage > SalesRule > Model > Rule` after line 117 add `const Your_Custom_ACTION = 'custom';`
And option will be added to your dropdown

**Override the above mentioned file/class, and do it a proper way**

Comment: @OSdave Yes thats obvious, I just gave him an idea how to do it

Comment: 1. Don't edit core files. 2. Don't edit core files. 3. If you're going to do it anyway, don't edit the core file in core/mage, do it in local/mage. But don't because you can generally just use an override if you need. And in this case you could just observe adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform... And do it without ever overriding a single core file.

Comment: Man, DON'T TOUCH in Core folder!